# Difference in Difference analysis via emmeans in R

Tags: r, lsmeans

Using emmeans, I have already coded for the difference and significance in means between: White Christian (WC) Men and Black Christian (BC) men, and then White Muslim (WM) men and Black Muslim (BM) men, for certain stereotype Dimensions. Here is my code for it:

`pairwise_emm2 <- emmeans(fitdata3, pairwise ~ Religion * Race | Dimension, type = "response") pairwise_emm2$contrasts`

I now want to code for the *differences between these differences*. Meaning I want to know if the WC-BC difference is greater than the WM-BM difference, and if it is significant. Can someone please help me figure out the code for that? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is an interaction contrast. Try

```
contrast(pairwise_emm2[[1]], interaction = "consec")
```

This calculates the difference of consecutive differences for each level of `Dimension`.

See `vignette("interactions", "emmeans")` for more discussion and examples

Or, you could compare the existing differences directly:

```
pairs(pairwise_emm2[[2]], simple = "contrast")
```

Comment: Thank you @RussLenth for your help so far! This is basically what I want, but in both options, it is not showing me all the possible difference - difference contrasts. For example with option 2 at the end of each Dimension it reads: [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 212 rows ] . Is their a way to specify a specific difference - difference contrast I want?

Comment: Your question suggests that you have 2 genders and 2 religions. That's one interaction contrast per dimension. If you have a lot more than that, then the numbers will grow quickly. I suggest not going overboard and testing too many things. You can use `at` in the emmeans call to use a smaller number of levels, and you can use a contrast family that gives only the comparisons you want.